# What does QGIS look for when displaying a projected SAR images in an HDF5 file and ENVI HDR file?

Tags: qgis, gdal, georeferencing, geocoding, hdf5

I have worked with ENVI HDR files and I know that the information tag which is used by QGIS is the `geo points` and `map info` tags. Which I generate by using GCP corner points and feeding them to `gdal_translate` and warping them to the projection required using `gdal_warp`.

I now have a dataset in HDF5 format which has lat long information which I convert to binary files of lat.bin and lon.bin, how do I preserve this information in my ENVI HDR files? If the image is a 3000*5000, I have the lat.bin and lon.bin at 350*350 at fixed spacing.

My current idea is convert that information into geo points and add as a field in the HDR image files' `.hdr` file. This is because I'm working with ENVI HDR file throughout my operations and the input data is in h5 format.